# 3D “goat grazing” problem on a cone

Tags: geometry, 3d

Here is a problem I created myself, but I’m not sure what the correct solution is.

A fly is tied to the end of a string with length $12$. The other end of the string is connected to the center of the base of a right circular cone with a radius of $6$ and a slant height of $12$. If both the fly and string cannot go inside of the cone, what is the volume of the space that the fly can visit?

Can this problem be solved using elementary techniques or will it require calculus? Thanks!

[image: FlyZone]

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Personally I avoid these types of problems because my visualization abilities (i.e eidetic imagery ability) is very low.  If I had to attack this problem, the first thing that I would try to do would be to look for some software that I could use to accurately create a 3-dimensional image of the problem.

Comment: @user2661923 I agree with you, a good diagram is needed for this problem.

Comment: The bottom half (below the cone, assuming the cone is suspended in the air) is a hemisphere, but the top half is a (hemi)torus but with the cone part removed. I don't think there is any way to find the volume except by calculus, using the [volume of revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution) of a [circular sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector).

Comment: Pappus's centroid theorem might be useful.

Comment: @random To find the geom. centroid, you need calculus, right?

Comment: I like your "no-fly" zone...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diagram below shows the cross-section of our 3D-Sketch which we added to the OP's problem statement. We denote the length of the string, to which the fly is tied, as $2r$. In order to avoid using calculus, we decided to consult tables where areas, volumes, and position of the centroids of various solids are tabulated.

[image: FlyZoneCS]

@random and @JaapScherphuis have briefly described in their comments what one has to do to solve this problem. So we know that the sought volume $V_\text{Fly}$ consists of two parts, i.e., a hemisphere ($V_1$) and a part of a horn torus ($V_2$). The solution given below was obtained by applying Pappus's Centroid Theorem to calculate the volume of the latter.

The volume of a hemisphere of radius $2r$ can be written as,
$$ V_1= \dfrac{16}{3}\pi r^3. \tag{1}$$

To find the volume of the part of a horn torus, we need to determine the area of a circular sector of radius $r$. Since this sector subtends an angle of $120^o$ at its center $A$, its area $A_s$ is given by,
$$A_s = \dfrac{\pi}{3}r^2. \tag{2}$$

Its centroid $G$ lies on its axis of symmetry $AH$ at a distance $AG=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{\pi}r\space$ from its center $A$. Therefore, the distance between $G$ and the axis of rotation, i.e. $z\text{-axis}$, is,
$$OK=r+AG\cos\left(60\right)=r\left(1+ \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2\pi}\right). \tag{3}$$

According to Pappus's second Centroid Theorem, we can express $V_2$ using (2) and (3) as shown below.
$$V_2= A_s ×2\pi×OK=\dfrac{\pi}{3}\left(2\pi+\sqrt{3}\right)r^3 \tag{4}$$

$$\therefore\enspace  V_\text{Fly} = V_1 +V_2 =\dfrac{\pi}{3}\left(2\pi+16+\sqrt{3}\right)r^3.$$

You may not like our solution, but you can at least use it to check the answer if someone posts the solution you are looking for.

Comment: I think this answer would benefit from some explanation of what it's doing; I did not see the relevance of anything that was going on until I looked up [Pappus's centroid theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus's_centroid_theorem). It also refers to a "solution given below" when there is nothing given below.

Comment: @MishaLavrov We expanded our answer to include the complete derivation.